# How to get ModelState error for Object List MVC/WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I've the following code snippet  where I get all my model error in "errors" variable but I want them Individually as per the object. would somebody please suggest How it can be achieved in an efficient way?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(List<Student> Students)
        {

            if (Students != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                          // Do some operation
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = new List<string>();
                foreach (var state in ModelState)
                {
                  foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
                  {
                     errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                  }
                }
              return errors;
            }
        }
```

Yes each propery for each object of list, Lets say I have two objects of Student and first one is doesn't have fname and 2nd one doesn't have lname then I want them as follows in json

```
{ 0:{[{ key:'fname', error:'fname is required' }]}, 1:{[{ key:'lname', error:'lname is required' }]} }
```

Comment: Do you want the error message associated with each property that has an error?

Comment: Yes each propery for each object of list, Lets say I have two objects of Student and first one is doesn't have fname and 2nd one doesn't have lname then I want them as
{
0:{[{
 key:'fname',
error:'fname is required'
}]},
1:{[{
 key:'lname',
error:'lname is required'
}]}


}

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842873/find-updatemodel-fail-reason/25843085#25843085). It only gives the first error of each property - if a property has multiple errors, you would need a more complex grouping query

Comment: Please check the question for more clarity. Do you really think that the solution provided by you, will be able resolve my issue. I am okay with showing only one error per property

Comment: If you used that query (from the link) and were to return `Json(errors)` you would get `[{propertyName: [0].fname, errormessage: `fname is required'}, {propertyName: [1].lname, errormessage: `lname is required'}]` where `[#]` refers the the index of the item in the collection. Not sure if that meets your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61409/discussion-between-ajay-suwalka-and-stephen-muecke).